# RESTful java Client and HttpClient

Tags: java, curl, restlet

I have a Curl command which I use to execute in UNIX.

```
curl --digest -u 'user':'pass' 'https://<URL>/getCustomers' (which is working for me)
```

I was trying to do this using Java.

I tried using Restlet and also HttpClient, but none works. I don't know the exact way to implement that.

```
private static void get() {
try {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://<URL>/getCustomers");

    getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USER, PASSWORD));

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I don't know where I did the mistake, can you guys help me out?
The output is a JSON, can you guys let me know how to catch the output, too?

Comment: Compile-errors? Exceptions? Output?

Comment: Firstly you need to call setCredentials before execute.

Comment: @Fortega I have got HTTP Status 401, Authentication failed. But witht he same credentianls i can able to run from command using curl.

Answer (score 0):

Your question misses a few details such as what is the error you get.

I would suggest to read the HTTPClient documentation and more specifically the section about [authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) and how preemptive works.

Then instead of dealing directly with the status code and entity, you could turn over the fluent API as in

```
Executor executor = Executor.newInstance()
        .auth(new HttpHost("example.com"), "username", "password")
        .authPreemptive(new HttpHost("example.com"));

executor.execute(Request.Get("http://example.com/foobar.json"))
        .returnContent().asString();
```